# Is there a way to scaffold tests for .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, scaffolding

I'm looking for functionality similar to the ["Create Unit Tests"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-test-basics?view=vs-2019#create-unit-test-projects-and-test-methods) feature of Visual Studio, for the .NET Framework (full/classic). I'm aware of "dotnet new mstest" or similar, but for an existing project, this does not work well, and will only generate one test file to start with.

I know of the [dotnet cli global tools feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools), but did some searching and didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Unit Test Boilerplate Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RandomEngy.UnitTestBoilerplateGenerator) from the Visual Studio Marketplace.

Also, please submit feedback (via Visual Studio) asking for [Create Unit Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-test-basics?view=vs-2019#create-unit-test-projects-and-test-methods) to be supported on .NET Core projects.